# Rails. Use different css file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, haml

I have two scss files with the same classes and two methods in main_controller.rb, which generate page1 and page2.

> = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'

in application.html.haml

How can I render two pages, which will use different scss files?

Answer (score 0):

app/controller/pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'for_another_page', only: :page2

  def page1
  end

  def page2
  end
end
```

app/view/layouts/for_another_page.html.erb

```
. . .
= stylesheet_link_tag 'another_scss_stylesheet'
. . .
```

config/enviroment/production.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( another_scss_stylesheet.css )
```

I think it should help for you more information on RailsGuides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: what is the app/view/layouts/for_another_page.rb ?

Comment: file contains the same code as in app/views/layout/application.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. It makes simple things unnecessarily complicated. And including separate CSS for each page is not a good practice.

Do this:

View

```
# app/views/page.html.erb
<div class="#{action_name}">
   <div class="page-content"></div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.page1 {
  .page-content { background: red; }
}

.page2 {
  .page-content { background: green; }
}
```

Comment: @itsnikolay, this is for OP's purpose.

Comment: @BillyChan but it seems here says it is ok https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css